Why the value of $\int_2^4 (x-4)(x-2)dx$ is not zero?
In the integral $\int_2^4 (x-4)(x-2)dx$, if we substitute $(x-4)(x-2)$ as z then both the limits become $0$. So, we can conclude that the definite integral has value zero without even thinking of what will happen to the integrand after substitution. But that is not the case, wolfram alpha calculated the value of integral as $-\frac{4}{3}.$
What is wrong in the first process?

The substitution is not monotone and so not inverible. Shift $\xi=x-3$ is a better choice.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Have a look at the conditions for u sub, in this case it's required that $\frac{z}{\frac{dz}{dx}}$ is continuous on the interval but it isn't at x=3 so can't do it.

Why do you expect the integral to be $0$ ? The integrated function is negative in $(2,4).$

@RolandF The flaw is not there. A substitution doesn't need to be invertible (see the example in the second part of my answer).

@Anne Bauval:   Non-monotone substitutions need a partion of the domain, generally. Counterexamples exist. Always.

The theorem requires no monotonicity assumption, and the proof involves no partition.

There are many similar questions on this site already. Here are a few: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/829939?lq=1

Your substitution is flawed because
$$d((x-4)(x-2))=d(x^2-6x+8)=(2x-6)dx\ne dx.$$
Your reasoning would apply to
$$\int_2^4(x-4)(x-2)(2x-6)dx=\int_0^0ydy=0.$$

I am concerned about the limits here. So far I know, if the limits are same, the result of the definite integral is zero, why should I be bothered about what happens to the integrand after substitution?

What you should be bothered about is doing the substitution correctly, i.e. not only in the integrand (the function), but also in the differential element. See the statement of the theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Statement_for_definite_integrals $\int_2^4(x-4)(x-2)dx\ne\int_2^4(x-4)(x-2)(2x-6)dx=\int_0^0ydy=0.$

If I substitute $(x-4)(x-2)$ by y then I cannot convert $2x-6$ into some function of $y$ as after solving the quadratic equation, two value of x will be found. Is this the logic you are trying to put?

No,  what I am saying is just that in order to perform this substitution, the factor $2x-6$ should have been  present in the integrand, to be grouped with $dx$, thus forming $dy$.

Let $ y = (x - 4)(x - 2) $.
$dy = (x - 4)dx + (x - 2)dx = (2x - 6)dx$
$dx = \frac{dy}{2x - 6}$
This does not help you to do the integral.
Now, draw the graph of $y$, which is a quadratic curve. You want to find the area under the graph.
By the quadratic formula, you get
$
x = 3 + \sqrt{1 + y} \quad \text{or} \quad x = 3 - \sqrt{1 + y}.
$
Consider
$
\int_{-1}^{0} (3 + \sqrt{1+y}) \, dy - \int_{-1}^{0} (3 - \sqrt{1+y}) \, dy.
$
You also get $\frac{4}{3} $, but it makes things more complex if you insist on doing such substitution.

How you got the upper and lower limits as 0 and -1 after substitution? If you put 4 and 2 in place of $x$ in the first line or even in the expression you got for $x$ using quadratic formula, then the value of y becomes 0.
